# How do you re-ignore files using .artifactignore with PublishPipelineArtifacts@2

Tags: azure-devops, continuous-integration, azure-pipelines

I have a .artifactignore at the root of my repository that looks like:

```
**/*
!**/bin/**/*
!**/obj/**/*
```

I can observe the .artifactignore being evaluated in the logs such as this:

```
Uploading pipeline artifact from d:\a\1\s for build #10471
Information, ApplicationInsightsTelemetrySender will correlate events with X-TFS-Session GUID
Information, DedupManifestArtifactClient will correlate http requests with X-TFS-Session GUID
Information, Using .artifactignore file located at: d:\a\1\s\.artifactignore for globbing
Information, Processing .artifactignore file surfaced 20721 files. Total files under source directory: 21471
```

This correctly excludes everything but bin and obj directories. I would like to extend this .artifactignore such that it has the additional behavior:

- Ignores all pdb files regardless of their location

I have tried several variations:

```
**/*
!**/bin/**/*
!**/obj/**/*
*.pdb
```

```
**/*
!**/bin/**/*
!**/obj/**/*
.pdb
```

```
**/*
!**/bin/**/*
!**/obj/**/*
**/*.pdb
```

```
**/*
!**/bin/**/*
!**/obj/**/*
!!*.pdb
```

```
**/*
!**/bin/**/*
!**/obj/**/*
!!**/*.pdb
```

```
**/*
!**/bin/
!**/obj/
!!**/*.pdb
```

With several other variations I'm sure. All of these contain all of the .pdb files that are present in the bin folders.

How do I publish all the bin and obj folders without bringing along the .pdb files?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> How do I publish all the bin and obj folders without bringing along the .pdb files?

I am afraid there is no such out of box syntax you could **re-include a file if a parent directory of that file is excluded**.

That means, you use the syntax `!**/bin/**/*` to exclude the parent folder `bin` from the `.artifactignore` file, you could not re-use the syntax `*.pdb` or any other to **re-include** the file `.pdb`.

As the document state:

> Refer to the [Git guidance](https://git-scm.com/docs/gitignore) on the `.gitignore` syntax, **the syntax for
>   .artifactignore is the same**.

To check the details info, you could refer [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5533050/gitignore-exclude-folder-but-include-specific-subfolder/20652768#20652768) about `.gitignore` syntax.

As workaround for this issue, we could use following syntax to including all the file types except the `.pdb` file:

```
**/*

!**/bin/**/*.dll
!**/bin/**/*.xml
!**/bin/**/*.config

!**/obj/**/*.dll
!**/obj/**/*.xml
!**/obj/**/*.config
```

Hope this helps.